# Texture from MTL file not being correctly applied to OBJ model in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am loading a 3D model using 3 files I've been provided with:

- example.obj
- example.mtl
- example.jpg

I am loading them in my Three.js script with this snippet:

```
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setPath('./');
        mtlLoader.load('example.mtl', function(materials) {
            materials.preload();
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('./');
            objLoader.load('example.obj', function(obj) {
                scene.add(obj);
            }, onProgress, onError);
        });
```

The model is displayed on screen and the textures applied, but incorrectly (textures are not properly assigned to each face, look rotated, etc). Looks like the texture mapping is incorrect. Since the snippet is so simple and everything seems to be set automatically I'm not sure what I could do to try to fix it. Any idea?

BTW, the files were exported from Zbrush.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example of what it looks like vs. what it should look like? It could be something to do with the model UV's not being correct when exporting from Zbrush, hence the incorrect mapping of the texture.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the files in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments but I finally found out what the problem was: Zbrush was exporting the textures upside down. I corrected them and the issue was fixed. Thanks again.